# eclipse .jar export

Tags: java, eclipse

Just finished my project in Eclipse, using Sphinx for voice recognition. In eclipse the program runs fine, but after i export the .jar and run it from command line i get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/cmu/sphinx/util/p
rops/ConfigurationManager
        at edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.helloworld.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.Configura
tionManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Anyone knows what i-m doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: added the jar to your class path, in env. variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the third party (Sphynx) is missing from your classpath
try:

java -cp ; classname .....